# How to skip the default value

Tags: typescript

I have a class that has three properties. The second property has a default value. When creating an instance of a class, how to skip it? For example:

```
class Car {
    public name: string;
    public price: number = 40_000;
    readonly o: number;

    constructor(name: string, price: number, o: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.o = o;
    }
}




const car1 = new Car ('audi', , 2)
car.name = 'audi'
car.o = 2
```

How not to set a value for the `price` property so that the default value is used? With such a syntax `const car1 = new Car ('audi', , 2)`, TypeScript thinks that 2 is the price and asks to specify another value for the property 'o'

```
car1 // {name: 'audi', price: 40000, 0: 2}
```

Comment: As written you'd have to do `new Car("foo", undefined as unknown as number, 123);` (and I think even then would end up without getting the default value). Why not use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), so the default's on the _parameter_? Then `new Car("foo", undefined, 123);` works.